# `plt.legend` in matplotlib, seaborn: How does the `loc` parameter work?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

- I am a beginner in Python doing an online course. The following is an abstracted version of a given solution in the course.
- In one exercise a `seaborn` plot is generated and a `legend` is added.
- **Issue:** I do not understand how the legend is on the right side based on the parameters that are used. How is `loc = 'center left'` placing the `legend` on the right side of the plot?
- The [`matplotlib` manual](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html) says:

> The strings 'upper center', 'lower center', 'center left', 'center
> right' place the legend at the center of the corresponding edge of the
> axes/figure.

- I am sure that there is a logical answer but I am not able to see it :).

---

### Code Listing

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sb

# https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-to-create-pandas-dataframe/
# initialize data of lists.
data = {'Name':['Tim', 'Tom', 'Cindy', 'Mandy'],
        'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18],
        'Gender':['Male', 'Male', 'Female', 'Female']}
 
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

sb.barplot(data = df, x = 'Name', y = 'Age',  hue = 'Gender')
plt.legend(loc = 'center left', bbox_to_anchor = (1, 0.5)) # legend to right of figure
```

---

### Screenshots

[image]

[image]

*(https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interpretation of `loc` changes unintuitively when you also pass a coordinate argument for `bbox_to_anchor`. When both are present, the `loc` *of the legend box* is anchored on the `bbox_to_anchor` coordinate.

So what you have done is asked it to align the legend such that the box is left-aligned and vertically-centered on the (1, .5) coordinate of the axes, which puts it outside of the plot to the right.

To put it where you expect, you could do `loc="center left", bbox_to_anchor=(0, .5)`. Or just don't set `bbox_to_anchor`, which is only really relevant when you want to fine-tune the position beyond the 9 points you can spell out in `loc`. E.g., if you want the legend in the lower right-hand of the axes, but padded a bit from the corner, you could do `loc="lower right", bbox_to_anchor=(.85, .15)`.

Comment: Ah, thanks, that is helpful information. The documentation did not make sense to me.

Comment: Yes I agree. If you understand the details of how the default `bbox_to_anchor` works the behavior is _logical_, even though it is unintuitive, but I think the section in the docs that your highlighted is incorrect or at best misleading.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is due to the difference between a figure and an axis.

Matplotlib has two objects: figures and axes. A figure is the overall plot that matplotlib is drawing and axes are the individual axes for plotting something. For example, you may have a figure with four axes for four individual subplots.

You can work without axes e.g.

```
plt.plot(x,y)
```

or with axes e.g.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.plot(x,y)
```

I believe (and would love for someone more experienced to delve deeper into this distinction) it is generally better to work with axes as it gives you more control as you create more complex figures.

So, what does this have to do with Seaborn? Well, I am pretty sure that Seaborn always works with axes. What this means is that `plt.legend` is drawing a legend on the last used axes and NOT on the specific axis that Seaborn drew. As a result, the normal placement options don't work.

What you can do instead is to create a variable to get the axis created by Seaborn so you can draw the legend on that axis:

```
ax = sb.barplot(data = df, x = 'Name', y = 'Age',  hue = 'Gender')
ax.legend(loc = 'center left', bbox_to_anchor = (1, 0.5))
```

Alternatively, you can define the axis prior to plotting.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
sb.barplot(data = df, x = 'Name', y = 'Age',  hue = 'Gender', ax=ax)
ax.legend(loc = 'center left', bbox_to_anchor = (1, 0.5))
```

Comment: I gave the answer a +1, thanks! But want to wait for others to reply before I accept an answer. I am relieved that it also seems weird to you.

Comment: Not a problem, I wouldn't mind seeing another explanation myself as I am self-taught and have more than a few gaps in my knowledge. Rest assured that even after plotting thousands of times using MPL/Seaborn I still run into issues like you have described. For example, getting a single legend for multiple subplots that were plotted using seaborn is not a straightforward task!

Comment: This answer is actually incorrect. Plt.legend draws on the last axes used.  However in general it is preferable to use the explicit interface rather than pyplot.